# Updating multiple create_text objects in Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to continuously update a time output overlayed on a canvas with a background. I can do this when the text is on a label, but the label doesn't allow me to add multiple text objects without creating a background around the text. I am able to add a static time, but as soon as I try to create a function to simply create a text I seem to get an error

So this code works fine:

```
timenow = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 333)
c.pack()
image = PhotoImage(file = 'C:/Users/Khalid Byra/Desktop/Python Alarm Clock Project/wallpaper.gif')
c.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor=NW)
c.create_text(250, 166.5, text = timenow, font=('Arial', 24), fill = 'white', anchor = CENTER)
```

However, when I try change it to a method like this:

```
c.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor=NW)
def write(x=250, y=166.5, text=timenow, font=('Arial', 24), fill='white', anchor=CENTER):
    c.create_text(x, y, text, fill, anchor, text)
write()
```

I get the following error:

```
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
```

_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "22:27:34"

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind I figured it out, was supposed to do this:

def write(x=250, y=166.5, text=timenow, font=('Arial', 32), fill='white', anchor=CENTER):
    c.create_text(x, y, text=text, fill=fill, anchor=anchor)

My next problem is that I am using this method to update the clock:

```
def tick():
    global timenow
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if time2 != timenow:
        timenow = time2
        write(text = time2)
    c.after(200, tick)

tick()
```

But the problem here is that it puts new text over the old one, making it a mess. So now I need to figure out to delete the old text as the new one appears? But it's not assigned to variable so I'm not sure how

Comment: Well, you need to assign it to a variable so that you can refer to it later.  Note that it would be more efficient, and likely simpler, to simply change the text of the existing item (via `.itemconfig()` on the Canvas), than to constantly delete and recreate the item.

Comment: Thanks I literally just figured this out, tried the itemconfig() before but I didn't do it write, the following code works perfectly:
def tick():
    global timenow
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if time2 != timenow:
        timenow = time2
        c.itemconfigure(a, text = time2)
    c.after(200, tick)